# What's the word for qualifying something that conforms to one or several musical conventions?

Tags: word-request

I am thinking "melodic" might be one of them, but there are probably many words, because melody is only one aspect of musical conventions, so please tell me if you know one, and also I think there's a word to qualify something that conforms to all conventions, or some of them, but I have no idea what it might be. I think conventional is too general and doesn't really pertain to music specifically.

For example:

> Her musical composition was ____.

Comment: When I search for "musical conventions" online I find two possibilities, (a) the composition or conventions of "musicals" (think: Oklahoma!) and (b) A group of music-loving people getting together to talk about music.  I don't understand how "melodic" is a "convention" of music.  Can you [edit] your post to include a description and link to a definition of what you mean by "musical conventions?"  As written, your sample sentence could legitimately conclude with almost any adjective in the dictionary.  (I'm fond of "contumacious.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think single word could fit here.

If it conforms to a particular set of conventions which define a genre, you can say it is of that genre:

> Her composition was an elegant serialist piece (follows the conventions of serialism)
>
> She wrote perfectly structured Classical sonata.  (the conventional style popular 1750-1800)
>
> It was a fusion of jazz and death-metal (conforms to the conventions of both genres)